# *-network UNCLAIMED : How can I fix this issue

Tags: linux-networking, ubuntu-14.04, ethernet, eth0, modprobe

Out of the blue my second ethernet port stopped working. 
Both of them are part of the motherboard.

I can see both of the ports in bios. They were working, but I was using only one of them up to now. `/etc/network/interface` is correctly setup and  changed the settings between, eth0 and eth1.

`sudo modprobe tg3` did not help either, (since in the documentation it sais this is the mod for the two Ethernet ports/cards.)

**Is it a lost cause, has it gone bad or can it be fixed?**

`lshw -C network`

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: NetXtreme BCM5721 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 11
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 66MHz
   capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: iomemory:ffffffff0-fffffffef
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: NetXtreme BCM5721 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 11
   serial: 00:1c:23:1c:af:8c
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.134 duplex=full firmware=5721-v3.61, ASFIPMI v6.21 ip=***.***.***.*** latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
```

Note: I also tried a live Ubuntu 14.04 cd and I had the same problems.

---

`lspci -v`

```
 03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5721 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell PowerEdge 860
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [50] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00


  04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5721 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell PowerEdge 860
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at fe7f0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Expansion ROM at <ignored> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [50] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
```

Comment: What driver is eth0 using? lspci -v. What does dmesg say about all this?

Comment: Kernel driver in use: tg3

Comment: And does dmesg say anything when the system boots about eth0-1 or tg3?

Comment: There are a lot of messages for `eth0`, which look normal, no messages for `eth1`, and the only weird for `tg3` was:
tg3 0000:03:00.0: Cannot map device registers, aborting
tg3: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -12

Comment: Not good. Can you try a different operating system? FreeBSD, Windows, something? Just to see if the NIC will be detected. I'm guessing it's a hardware problem though.

Comment: Thank you, I will. (I already tried Ubuntu live and Gparted live cd so I do not have my hopes up) (I will try something non Debian but still..)